# Python Selenium: datepicker selecting day

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to **scrape** some data from the web using selenium. At one part I need to change the day of a datepicker.

[image]

I marked red the part I need to change, in this case the "15" to e.g. "13".

I tried:

```
dep_date_day_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//table[@class='BpkCalendarGrid_bpk-calendar-grid__3AlVL FlightDatepicker_fsc-datepicker__list-size__zQzUm']")
dep_date_day_button.click()
dep_date_day_button2 = dep_date_day_button.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='BpkCalendarDate_bpk-calendar-date__3VYKN BpkCalendarDate_bpk-calendar-date--focused__4eiYn BpkCalendarDate_bpk-calendar-date--selected__3v5jT']")
```

But get the error message:

NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class='BpkCalendarDate_bpk-calendar-date__3VYKN BpkCalendarDate_bpk-calendar-date--focused__4eiYn BpkCalendarDate_bpk-calendar-date--selected__3v5jT']"}

Any idea how I could access and change the day?

I also tried

```
dep_date_day_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//table[@class='BpkCalendarGrid_bpk-calendar-grid__3AlVL FlightDatepicker_fsc-datepicker__list-size__zQzUm']")
dep_date_day_button.click()  
dtd0_button = dep_date_button.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[contains(@class, 'BpkCalendarDate_bpk-calendar-date__3VYKN') and (@aria-label, 'Thursday, 12 September 2019')]")
```

Comment: it seems like I need to get the "aria-pressed" in the line above to true, but I have no idea how? do I need somehow loop through all the rows of the table?

Comment: I looked at lots of Java code but unfortunately I am not able to transfer it to python...

Comment: According to your screenshot, the button's class doesn't contain `BpkCalendarDate_bpk-calendar-date--focused__4eiYn`. Shouldn't this be `BpkCalendarDate_bpk_ed__4eiYn`?

Comment: thanks @ForceBru for your help! it seems like the approach does not work as the class name changes if selected....